# Word for a gift or debt that is so great it is not repayable

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for the word that describes a gift or debt that is so great it is not repayable (such as a parent’s gift of life. The child can never equally repay that). When I was in university, I learned there was a word for this.

I’ve tried googling this, but all that comes up are links regarding money.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Augustine wrote of his god's plenitude as an *incommensurate* gift.

Comment: Are you sure you're thinking of a noun (as you describe it)? Because adjectives come to mind: invaluable, priceless, inestimable

Comment: Would *unrepayable* be too simple?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.yourdictionary.com/incomparable

incomparable in·com·pa·ra·ble

that cannot be compared; specif.,
having no common basis of comparison; incommensurable
beyond comparison; unequaled; matchless: incomparable skill

incomparable
adjective

Being such that comparison is impossible; incommensurable.
So outstanding as to be beyond comparison; unsurpassed.

http://searchsentences.com/words/incomparable-in-a-sentence

11. Of that unique and *incomparable* collection not a vestige remained!
12. How hard she would strive to be worthy of this *incomparable* gift!
13. She fled along the cliff-path and an *incomparable* horror was in her soul.

Comment: The term *incomparable* means that the thing in question cannot be compared, which raises the question: cannot be compared to **what**? Unless the context makes that clear, the expression is incomplete. What the OP is looking for is a word that means specifically that the thing cannot be compared to anything that one might attempt to offer as a repayment, not just the word that means that it cannot be compared to something or other.

Comment: the gift stands alone - it cannot be compared to anything. Comparison is impossible.